# Hadoop edge node Issues

Tags: java, hadoop, oom

Trying to submit job to dataproc cluster from edge node.
Getting error - My java version installed
which java
/usr/bin/java

openjdk version "1.8.0_332"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Temurin)(build 1.8.0_332-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Temurin)(build 25.332-b09, mixed mode)

```
    Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at sun.misc.IOUtils.readNBytes(IOUtils.java:213)
    at sun.misc.IOUtils.readAllBytes(IOUtils.java:116)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:441)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.checkForSpecialAttributes(JarFile.java:575)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.hasClassPathAttribute(JarFile.java:538)
    at java.util.jar.JavaUtilJarAccessImpl.jarFileHasClassPathAttribute(JavaUtilJarAccessImpl.java:37
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getClassPath(URLClassPath.java:1212)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:533)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getNextLoader(URLClassPath.java:495)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:249)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:601)>
```

Comment: Add more RAM to your node

Comment: Thanks
 This issue is because of i forgot to mention g with memory options in saprk-submit.
it got fixed.
But getting different error now:
 does not existread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:<full ptah & filename> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:634)